# How make my pyqt5 frameless application which maximizes to Max according to different resolutions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I already have a custom frameless window application in Pyqt5. I just want the application to be once opened, get to full size depending upon the different resolutions of different PC's.

I want only **_** and **X** buttons and not a **[]** (maximize) button, because I want it to maximize automatically. Is there any way to do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that solution. We can do that by :

```
from PySide import QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
screen_resolution = app.desktop().screenGeometry()
width, height = screen_resolution.width(), screen_resolution.height()
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to achieve that is to use a combination of [`showMaximized()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#showMaximized) and the disabled `WindowMaximizeButtonHint` [window flag](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum):

```
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(
            self.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint)

# ...
myWindow = MyWindow()
myWindow.showMaximized()
```

The only problem with this is that (at least on Windows) as soon as you disable the maximize button, the window becomes movable.